# jQuery.ajax() does not work from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am encountering an issue wherein the following piece of code works fine when I keep it outside any function in javascript BUT it throws 'object does not support method or property ajax' error when this is kept inside a javascript function. Kindly help.

The below works well and prints message on console:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "upStreamStatus.jsp",
          success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //$("#crdStatus").html(data);
                //crdContents.text(data);
          }
      });
</script>
```

BUT, the below code fails with 'object does not support method or property ajax' error :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function get_live_crdStatus(){
              jQuery.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "upStreamStatus.jsp",
              success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
          });
      } 

$(document).ready(function(){
       get_live_crdStatus();

  });
    </script>
```

[Error displayed in IE11 developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktQmf.png)

[Object Does not support property or method ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCEqy.png)

I am not sure why the placement of the jQuery.ajax()  block within a function is creating an issue. Request you to kindly provide your help / inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using exact same jQuery.js source? Sounds like you have a *"slim"* version with no ajax api in it for second instance.

Comment: <head> in HTML contains: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, the jquery.ajax works well when placed directly in <script> and outside of any function.

Comment: Basics of your code work fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/ABwoMtFInt5jG6hjEsxY?p=preview.

Comment: Make sure you aren't loading another version of jQuery.js that is a *"slim"* version after you load the one shown

Comment: I am not using the slim version

Comment: Something not shown is wrong then. Can clearly see in above demo that the code works. What version of IE are you running this in?  jQuery 3.1 doesn't support older IE versions Does same error occur in other browsers?